# Reverse Words in String

Tags: c

For some reason, I can't get this to work! Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong? This is supposed to reverse the words in a give string (i.e from "this is a test" to "test a is this")

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *reverse(char const *input)
{
    char *ret = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(input));
    int length = 0;
    int numWords = 1;
    int i;
    for(i=0; input[i]!=NULL; i++)
    {
        length++;
        if(input[i]==' ')
            numWords++; 
    }
    char words[numWords];
    int currentWord = numWords;
    for(i=0; input[i]!=NULL; i++)
    {
        if (input[i]==' '){
            currentWord--;
        }else{
            words[currentWord] = words[currentWord] + input[i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i < numWords; i++)
    {
        ret = ret + words[i];
    }

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int nTestcase = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char inputstr[100];
    char *reversedStr = NULL;
    scanf("%d\n", &nTestcase);
    for (i = 0; i < nTestcase; i++)
    {
        fgets(inputstr, 100, stdin);
        reversedStr = reverse(inputstr);
        printf("%s\n", reversedStr);
        free(reversedStr);
        memset(inputstr, 0, 100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  Which part doesn't work?

Comment: what is you meant by this line in your code  words[currentWord] = words[currentWord] + input[i]; ???  your are adding two characters and storing it in another!!

Comment: Looks too complicated. Why do you care about the number of words? Just start at the end and scan backward looking for spaces; when you find one, print the part of the string starting with the character after the space and ending before the next space.

Comment: '+' operator in c in not overloaded to string concatenation. you are using + operators for that in two for loops

Comment: There's an off-by-one in the malloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words[currentWord] = words[currentWord] + input[i];
```

You can't add characters to each other like that expecting string concatenation. And I imagine you expect `words` to be an array of words (i.e. strings), but its type is not that, `words` is just an array of characters.

Like @Tom said, you're doing this again in the last for loop:

```
ret = ret + words[i];
```

Comment: in last for loop also he is using '+' for concatenation- ret = ret + words[i]

Answer (score 0):

Joseph, unlike other programming languages ( c# or PHP ), string handling functions of C are quite basic.

You cannot add strings directly, however there are a host of library functions you can use to accomplish the same task.

Check out,

- strtok - Use it to split the string to words. [strtok reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)
- strncat - Use to concatenate strings

strings in C are just byte arrays terminated with the null character ( byte with value 0).

Answer (score 0):

Here is shorter/cleaner way

```
private char[] reverseWords(char[] words) {

    int j = words.length - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < (words.length)/2; i++) {
        if(i==j)
            continue;

        char temp = words[i];
        words[i] = words[j];
        words[j]=temp;
        j--;
    }
    int lastIndex = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
        if(words[i]==' '){
            words = reverseWord(words,lastIndex,i-1);
            lastIndex=i+1;
        }
    }
    words = reverseWord(words,lastIndex,words.length-1);

    return words;
}

private char[] reverseWord(char[] words, int from, int to) {
    int j=to;
    for(int i=from;i<((to/2)+from/2);i++){
        if(i==j) continue;

        char temp = words[j];
        words[j]=words[i];
        words[i]=temp;
        j--;
    }
    return words;
}
```